# How to get a specific value from an array of object and store them individually ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I was wondering on how to get a specific value from an array of object.

```
const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([{
serviceValue:"",
quantityValue:"",
amountToPay:""
}]);
```

and map them individually from a separate constant/useState.
ex.

```
const [service,setServiceValue] = useState([]); //serviceValue[]
const [quantity,setQuantityValue] = useState([]);//quantityValue[]
const [amountToPay,setAmountToPay] = useState([]);//amountToPay[]
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I've used Sir Abhishek's solution by doing this

```
    const [serviceItem, setServiceList] = useState([{serviceValue:"", 
        quantityValue:"",amountToPay:""}]);
    console.log(serviceItem);

    const [amountToPay, setAmountToPay] = useState([]);
    console.log("AMOUNT TO PAY",amountToPay)
      useEffect(()=>{
        serviceItem.map((item) => (
            setAmountToPay([...amountToPay,item.amountToPay])
        ))
    }, [serviceItem])
```

The problem now is everytime I change the state of the input, it also records the previous input creating multiple array of object

this is the [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdv6A.png)

The reason why I need the current value of amountToPay is I need the sum by using .reduce

Comment: Just do this: 
setAmountToPay(item.amountToPay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may use **map** function for that*

```
itemList.map((item)=>{
setServiceValue([...serviceValue, item.serviceValue]);
setQuantityValue([...itemQuantity, item.quantityValue]);
setAmountToPay([...amountToPay,item.amountToPay]);
})
```

Comment: I have an error where it rerenders to many times.

Comment: `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop`

Comment: Try the code again. I have made some changes!

Comment: It worked but the problem now is every time I change the state, it renders all of the previous state.