# Save a specific value from an array of object and store them individually into another state to get the sum ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, jsx

In addition to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74499675/how-to-get-a-specific-value-from-an-array-of-object-and-store-them-individually/74509632?noredirect=1#comment131535317_74509632)
I am trying to map individually a state to another state to store the `amountToPay` object to get the sum of it. The problem is every time it renders the `onChange` function. It stores every state as object as you can see here: [image: here].

What I want to happen is to only get [`434`] instead of `['','4','43','434']`
So I can .reduce the array to get the sum.

My method on storing the array object to another state is this

```js
 const [amountToPay, setAmountToPay] = useState("")
 console.log("AMOUNT TO PAY", amountToPay)
 useEffect(() => {
   serviceItem.map((item) => (
     setAmountToPay([...amountToPay, item.amountToPay])
   ))
 }, [serviceItem])

 useEffect(() => {
   serviceItem.map((item) => (
     setAmountToPay([...amountToPay, item.amountToPay])
   ))
 }, [serviceItem])
```

You can check the whole code here [CodeSandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-leftpad-9ft2od?file=/src/App.js).Any help is appreciated  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things I suggest you to do:

1. Add some id property to your `serviceItem`. You can use `UUID`, `nanoid`, or even `Date.now()`
2. Remove `const [amountToPay, setAmountToPay] = useState([]);`
3. Use values directly from `serviceItem` collection. In order to do this you need to create onChange handler, it will be something like this

```js
const handleChange = (id) => (nextAmount) => {
    setServiceList(prevValue => {
       return prevValue.map(item => item.id === id ? { ...item, amount: nextAmount } : item) 
    }) 
}
```

And amount to pay can be easily got from `serviceItem` collection, without effects or other states

```
const procedurePriceTotal = serviceItem.reduce(
    (acc, item) => (acc = acc + item.amount),
    0
);
```

Comment: I followed this and did a little tweak. You can check my latest answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because you are setting **serviceItem** on onChange method
and use passed **serviceItem** as deps array to useeffect in which you are setting amountToPay.
so on every change it's appending in array

Rather then setting amount in *useEffect*, make a method and call on remove/add button so it will only call after user is finished typing. you can also place a button 'Save' or 'calculate Amount' and call **handleSetAmountToPAY** method which will update amount.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  //Values
  const [serviceItem, setServiceList] = useState([
    { serviceValue: "", quantityValue: "", amountToPay: "" }
  ]);
  console.log("SERVICE ITEM", serviceItem);

  //Add item function
  const handleItemAdd = () => {
    setServiceList([
      ...serviceItem,
      { serviceValue: "", quantityValue: "", amountToPay: "" }
    ]);
    handleSetAmountToPAY(serviceItem)
  };

  //Remove item function
  const handleItemRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...serviceItem];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setServiceList(list);
    handleSetAmountToPAY(list)
  };

  //Get Values
  const handleGetValues = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...serviceItem];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setServiceList(list);
  };

  //Saving state to another state
  const [amountToPay, setAmountToPay] = useState([]);
  console.log("AMOUNT TO PAY", amountToPay);
  const handleSetAmountToPAY =  (list) => {
    list && list.map((item) =>
      setAmountToPay([...amountToPay, item.amountToPay])
    );
  }

  //Add total amount
  const procedurePriceTotal = amountToPay.reduce(
    (index, value) => (index = index + value),
    0
  );
  console.log("TOTAL PRICE", procedurePriceTotal);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {serviceItem.map((singleItem, index) => (
        <div class="row form-row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>
                Service <span class="text-danger">*</span>
              </label>
              <input
                name="serviceValue"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                value={singleItem.serviceValue}
                placeholder="Tooth Extraction"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleGetValues(e, index);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>
                Quantity <span class="text-danger">*</span>
              </label>
              <input
                name="quantityValue"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="1"
                value={singleItem.quantityValue}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleGetValues(e, index);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>
                Amount (₱)<span class="text-danger">*</span>
              </label>
              <input
                name="amountToPay"
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="500"
                value={singleItem.amountToPay}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleGetValues(e, index);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
            <div class="add-more">
              <br />
              {serviceItem.length !== 1 && (
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={() => handleItemRemove(index)}
                  className="btn btn-primary rx-pr"
                >
                  <i className="fas fa-plus" /> Remove Item
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      {/* Add Item */}
      <div className="add-more-item rx-pr">
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={handleItemAdd}
          className="btn btn-primary rx-pr"
        >
          <i className="fas fa-plus" /> Add Item
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is okay but the problem is...
What if the user decides to click the button multiple times for some reason. It will always add the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it the wrong way.
I solved it by mapping the serviceItem then using `reduce` to get the sum instead of putting it again into a separate array of object then mapping it again to get the sum.

```
 const newNumberArray = serviceItem.map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item.amountToPay)
  })

 const totalAmountPaid =  newNumberArray.reduce((index,value) =>  index = index + value, 0 )
```

Thanks for all the help and suggestion!